# Why can’t I trigger this keydown event with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to apply my JavaScript algorithm to solve 2048 game.
http://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/

To do this first I wanted to add the possibility to simulate keydown events (left arrow, right, down, up) on the site with js

To do that I entered into the js console the following code:

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
```

Now I have jQuery on the site. Then I wanted to test if simulating keydown events works:

```
var e = $.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 39}); 
$("body").trigger(e);
```

But it seems that the event isn’t invoked :(

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2048 page does not have nor use jQuery. From [here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/) you can see that "The .trigger() function cannot be used to mimic native browser events"

Also found at that site is another jQuery library, jquery.simulate.js, which allows for simulating native browser events.

You must remember that jQuery !== JavaScript. If the website does not use jQuery to begin with, adding it most likely will not produce a viable solution.

Comment: are you kidding me? I wrote: var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);

Comment: So that  I have jquery on the site yes ?

Comment: @Snorlax The answer is not a joke. The authors of the site did not include, nor use jQuery. Your actions have nothing to do with how their site works so it doesn't matter if you put jQuery there or not. The fact of the matter is that `.trigger()` does not work when you're triggering native events and given that they didn't use jQuery you'll either need to find their framework or use JavaScript to trigger **native** JavaScript events.

Comment: but I included jquery using var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq); so that I think that now I can use jquery on this site via console

Comment: @Snorlax, this is the last time I'll tell you this. **It doesn't matter if YOU can use jQuery, the site doesn't use jQuery so you can't trigger jQuery events. jQuery events are NOT JavaScript events. You need to trigger JavaScript events instead.**